# XML schema element name flexibility

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have xml that could be

```
<group>
  <location/>
  <persistent/>
</group>
```

or

```
<group>
  <ui-location/>
  <persistent/>
</group>
```

Is there a way to have a wildcard for ui- part or is there some way to say that the element that appear there can be either location or ui-location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in answer to the 2nd part of your question. You can use `xsd:choice`:

> element that appear there can be either location or ui-location

```
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xsd:element name="location" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="ui-location" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:sequence>
```

Comment: And to answer the first part, too:  no, no wildcards in declared names in XSD.